# Easy WP SMTP v1.0.7 does not send email

Tags: wordpress

I have used Easy WP SMTP v1.0.7 plugin to send mail.

but i got this error when testing mail.

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (1655685655)
<br />
```

Answer (score 1):

hurray ! i got my answer

```
Edit php.ini and uncomment extension_dir=ext.
Also uncomment extension=php_openssl.dll.
```

its works well..... :)

Comment: What is the path of php.ini file ?